# How to Get Site-users and Site-groups in SPFx using PnP-JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, groups, pnpjs

How to get the site users and site groups in SPFx using PnP JS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Site Users**:

You can get the site users using `pnp.sp.web.siteUsers` as given below:

```
$pnp.sp.web.siteUsers.get().then(function(data) {
    var users = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        users += data[i].Id + " - " + data[i].Title + "<br/>";
    }
    console.log(users);
});
```

**Reference**: [Pnp-JS-Core: Gets all users from Site Collection](https://www.ktskumar.com/2016/07/pnp-js-core-gets-users-site-collection/).

**Site Groups**:

You can get the site users using `pnp.sp.web.siteGroups` as given below:

```
$pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.get().then(function(data) {
    var groups = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        groups += data[i].Title + " - " + data[i].OwnerTitle + "<br/>";
    }
    console.log(groups);
});
```

**Reference**: [Pnp-JS-Core: Gets all groups from Site Collection](https://www.ktskumar.com/2016/07/pnp-js-core-get-groups-site-collection/).